# How to remove Chinese punctuation in Python

Tags: python, chinese-locale

I have the following sentences, that I want to remove all punctuation.

```
首页 » 政策法规 » 正文吉林省实施《中华人民共和国老年人权益保障法》若干规定   发布时间： 2008-01-04
```

I want to remove all Chinese punctuation, including empty space " ". Below is my code:

```
line = line.decode("utf8")
line = re.sub("[\s+\.\!\/_,$%^*(+\"\']+|[+——！，。？、~@#￥%……&*（）：；《）《》“”()»〔〕-]+".decode("utf8"), "".decode("utf8"),line)
```

However, I still got empty space not deleted. I wonder if there exist easier ways to remove Chinese punctuation?

Comment: I suppose to add another sentence `想做/ 兼_职/学生_/ 的 、加,我Q：  1 5.  8 0. ！！？？  8 6 。0.  2。 3     有,惊,喜,哦` in my question, but I can not post it.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Well, I think your example is enough and that sentence could be spam, so don't add it into the question.

Answer (score 9):

Cuz most Chinese punctuations are **unicode**, we have to convert the string to **unicode** in order to remove Chinese punctuation.

```
# !/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-  


import re
punc = "！？｡。＂＃＄％＆＇（）＊＋，－／：；＜＝＞＠［＼］＾＿｀｛｜｝～｟｠｢｣､、〃》「」『』【】〔〕〖〗〘〙〚〛〜〝〞〟〰〾〿–—‘’‛“”„‟…‧﹏."
punc = punc.decode("utf-8")
line = "测试。。去除标点。。，、！"
print re.sub(ur"[%s]+" %punc, "", line.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: That's good! Just remind to replace `ur` by `r` in Python 3; in Pandas, the similar strategy can be applied: `comments['chinese_review'].str.replace(r"[%s]+"%punc, "").astype(str)`

Comment: and in Python 3, there is no need to `.decode()` as well.

Answer (score -1):

re.sub is `sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`

as your code, `pattern` is unicode, `repl` is unicode too ( actually, not needed to decode ),

but `string` is utf-8 encoded strings not **unicode**.

Try this,

```
print re.sub(ur"[\s+\.\!\/_,$%^*(+\"\']+|[+——！，。？、~@#￥%……&*（）：；《）《》“”()»〔〕-]+", "", s.decode("utf8"))
```